# Accessing Guest OS with hostname in VMWare Fusion

Tags: networking, centos, vmware, hostname, cloudera

I am using CentOS (Cloudera CDH3 image) as a guest OS running in my VMWare Fusion. Everything works fine and I can access the guest machine through my MAC OS using the IP address. I am bridging the network between my MAC and VMWARE machine so the Guest is having a separate IP and I can successfully SSH to it using the IP. The problem I am facing is that there is no way to access the guest OS by hostname. I tried setting up a hostname on the guest OS but still MAC cannot connect to the machine using the hostname and it even doesn't recognize the guest hostname. I need this because I am using a library that receives a remote machine hostname as a parameter to connect. Unfortunately, it doesn't accept IP and I wasn't able to make it work so far. Any idea on how to solve this?

I even tried to use NAT for VMWare but CentOS doesn't connect to Internet when in this mode. I tried modifying manually but no success. here's the screenshot from the Guest OS (CentOS):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either you get this IP address entered into your DNS servers, or do this:

```
on your 'host' machine, edit `/etc/hosts`
add this line:
`<ip-address-of-your-VM> <hostname-you-wish-to-call>`
```